# how many mail can be send from php mail() function?

Tags: php, email

i m working on job portal, for job alert i am sending mail for each user as per his/her subscription using cron job of php script. i have more than 10000 users(jobseekers) in portal. does php native function mail() can send more than 10000 mail without using smtp or other mail server?

and sorry for bad English.

Comment: separate recipient mail-d by comma `,` mail() send mail to all recipient  but with same message

Comment: see the link you'll get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817234/limits-for-mail-function

Comment: Did you check the link???

Answer (score 3):

> can send more than 10000 mail without using smtp or other mail server?

No it cannot send even 1 email if you don't provide it either of them. If you don't provide an external smtp then you have to have a mail server installed on the machine itself. Once that is done, 10k mails are not a problem.

> Note:
>
> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger
>   volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP
>   socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>
> For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and »
>   PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

[Reference:](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: main problem is, when i was doing testing for mail script ,i used demo table of jobseekers in which only 15 records are there, it is working fine but when i changed demo table to original table no mails were send from script.structure of table are same of demo and original.

Comment: Your script probably timed out

Comment: i used my email id at interval of 1000 record for testing purpose , table start from my record only still no mail is received